# How can I write better code for passing key-value arguments?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I want to write code for Ruby in a more Ruby-like style and  ran into a problem when working with argument passing.

I have to see if `ABC` is nil or not. If `ABC` is nil, I would pass another symbol into `dosomething`, if not I would pass another type of hash value to compute.

Since Ruby is not like Java, it can pass a different type of argument (different keys).

How can I make the following code more beautiful?

Merging `do_manything`, `do_otherthings`, `do_manythings_again` into a single function is not the answer I because I would call `dosomething` in many places in my code:

```
if ABC.nil?
Apple.dosomething (:foo => DEF) { |a| 
     a.do_manything
     a.do_otherthings
     a.do_manythings_again  
}
else
Apple.dosomething (:bar => ABC) { |a| 
     a.do_manything
     a.do_otherthings
     a.do_manythings_again  
}
end
```

Comment: unless `ABC` can be `nil` and `false` (so you need to tell one from the another), it's not idiomatic to write an explicit `.nil?` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either switch the hash you send:

```
opts = ABC.nil? ? {foo:DEF} : {bar:ABC}
Apple.dosomething(opts) do |a|
  do_many_things
  do_other_things
  do_many_things_again
end
```

...or you can pass a lambda as the block:

```
stuff_to_do = ->(a) do
  do_many_things
  do_other_things
  do_many_things_again
end

if ABC.nil?
  Apple.dosomething(foo:DEF,&stuff_to_do)
else
  Apple.dosomething(bar:ABC,&stuff_to_do)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the ternary operator.

```
Apple.dosomething (ABC.nil? ? {foo:DEF} : {bar:ABC}) do |a|
  a.do_manything
  a.do_otherthings
  a.do_manythings_again
end
```

Here is the format
`condition ? return_if_true : return_if_false`

Comment: In a code review I'd argue that putting a ternary statement in the method call is not good practice.

Comment: Yes. Harder to read/more complicated -- though we can write that way, think of the long-term maintenance or what someone else would think as they encounter it. Any time we have to stop to parse out the code in our head we increase the chance of a bug. This particular use is fairly safe because it's a simple example. Imagine a method with a bunch of parameters, or a large hash initialization using ternary assignments, vs. one without, and find a happy medium of readability and conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
options = if ABC.nil? then { foo: DEF } else { bar: ABC } end

Apple.do_something options do |apple| 
  apple.instance_eval do
    do_many_things
    do_other_things
    do_many_things_again
  end
end
```

By convention, words in names and identifiers are separated by underscores (`_`) and `do`/`end` is used for multiple-line blocks.

Also, I believe this question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).